# Swift and Json array of dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, multidimensional-array

What is the right json to represent an array of dictionary plz

I have this struct in Swift

```
struct myResults: Codable {
    let type: String
    let results: [[String: String]]
}
```

I tried this json representation

```
{
   "type":"express",
   "results":[
  { "name": "Name1", "result": "Result1" },
  { "name": "Name2", "result": "Result2" },
  { "name": "Name3", "result": "Result3" }
]
 }
```

but it seems that the json is representing the field results as `results: [String]`
but I want to have json that represents `let results: [[String: String]]`

So I'm confused about what to write as a json to represent `let results: [[String: String]]`

Any help/idea plz ? Thank you
[image]

Comment: "but it seems that the json is representing the field results as results: [String]" No, that's not the case. Copy/paste your JSON in `https://jsonlint.com` if you present that presentation?

Comment: @Larme I copy/pasted it also in "https://app.quicktype.io/" and it says that my json represents  results: [String] ... You check it if you want plz

Comment: "and it says that my json represents results: [String]" No, it doesn't say that. You are misreading the code. `Result` could be written: `struct Result {let name: String; let result: String }`, and it's an Object, so it's more or like a Dictionary equivalent to JSON. And since it's `let results: [Result]`, here `results` is an Array of `Result`, so an Array of Dictionary.

Comment: If `results` was indeed a `[String]`, the JSON would be ... `"results": ["name", "Name1", "result", "Result1", "name", "Name2", "result", "Result2", "name", "Name3", "result", "Result3"]`. `{`, `:`, `[` have meaning in JSON.

Comment: @Larme Now it's more clear ... and the json is correct as well ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value through the index so use like results: [String] or better to use your model to get the string values.

Comment: No but my json is wrong ... so I'm looking for the right json to represent let results: [[String: String]]

Comment: You can ask backend guy to change it or you can get values from the specific index based on that you can get the name and result

Answer (score 0):

let params: [String:Any] = [
"type":"express",
"results": [[
"name": "Name1", "result": "Result1" ,
"name": "Name2", "result": "Result2" ,
"name": "Name3", "result": "Result3" ,
]]]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).